# L2 Topology - looping

Tags: layer2

I am having some issues creating some redundancy with an L2 network.

I have a main tcom room with my distribution switches, and a switch room with 5 floor switches.
As it stands, I only have the infrastructure for 2 trunks from the tcom room to the switch room, so I can't create a full mesh.

The image below shows the current setup, however if for instance I lose switch 3, I also lose 4 and 5. So I am looking for some kind of redundancy should a switch die.

Do I need a full mesh between switches 1-5? (thus using up 4 ports on every switch?)

I am running HP Procurves using rpvst spanning-tree.

[image: network]

Comment: Could you update the lot of us towards what is your vertical cabling composed of between all your switches?

Comment: Cat5e between floor switches, fiber between switch room and telecom room.

Comment: Cat5e will be a bottleneck if you have to upgrade to 10G between your switches so your clients can all access these SMB shares/files on the servers concurrently and game too!. Investing in Cat6a shielded, SM (preferred) or OM4 fiber could provide the opportunity to redesign your topology. We use bidi 10G SFPs over SM to maximise our use of the fiber cores between our buildings/switches.

Comment: This is a very small network. Internet connectivity right now is only 4xT1, so they aren't pushing a lot of traffic.

Comment: No reason to allocate funds for an upgrade to fiber then. Ylearn has the simplest solution that works :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the switch room devices are all equally capable, then the simple solution would be to move the connection from *DistSw2 --> FloorSw2* to *DistSw2 --> FloorSw5*.

Uses no more ports and provides full redundancy from any single failure. A better solution that what you currently have in place with a minimum of changes.

Of course, if FloorSw3-5 each had their own connection to both FloorSw1 and FloorSw2, then you may be able to experience multiple failures and still maintain most of your operations.

Redundancy is great and we love making things as redundant as possible. However redundancy does have it's costs (in money, hardware, ports, power, cooling, etc). How much you spend on building redundancy into a network will depend on your business needs. The less tolerance for downtime, the more redundancy you will have to provide.

Comment: Well, now I feel a little silly. This was an easier solution (and much cheaper) than I was thinking.
Time for me to go home.

Answer (score -1):

Layer 2 redundancy is slow to converge. Spanning-tree is not a protocol meant to assure redundancy.

Also be careful that layer2 is not routed: usually one of your red link will be cut by the protocol. That means that for a host plugged on floorSw5 to speak to a host on floorSw1, it will not be routed directly via: distSw2 -> distSw1 -> floorSw1, even if it would take less hops.

Last but not least, spanning tree is based on timeouts, which means that you are not allowed to cascade more than 7 switches (you already have 6).
If for some reason you artificially lower the timeouts, this setup may become less stable.

If you can not come with a full layer3 network, I would suggest looking at the next generation datacenter switches with network fabric and trill (which is basically a routing infrastructure for layer2 devices).

Comment: Yes, STP is slow, but we are not addressing STP. RSTP is not slow. Max convergence time by default is 6 seconds. In event of a link failure, which covers most redundancy scenarios, it is more like dozens of milliseconds (a few hundred at most). This beats the majority of L3 redundancy scenarios (especially with default settings). Your second point would entirely depend on a number of unknown factors (link speed, etc) and can be balanced since this is a PV version of ST. The maximum diameter rule doesn't apply to pure RSTP networks because it doesn't depend on timers to transition ports.

Comment: [This post](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/23427/20558) tends to disagree with you. However, on small networks where 6 seconds cuts are acceptable, a full layer 2 network is common.

Comment: That post is comparing spanning tree to link aggregation, which is also a mechanism that can provide L2 redundancy (in addition to increased capacity). Yes, it is even faster than RSTP and in comparision RSTP may be considered slow, but that doesn't disagree with anything I said in comparing RSTP to L3 redundancy. And you stick to the 6 second max convergence time, even though most events in RSTP are a few hundred milliseconds at most.